# av_find_stream_info works OK with file, not with pipe

Tags: c, ffmpeg, pipe, libavformat

I have the following code:

```
av_register_all();
pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
const char* input = "pipe:";
AVInputFormat* iFormat = av_find_input_format("mpegts");
if ( avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, input, iFormat, NULL) != 0 )
         return -1;
int res = av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx);
```

when my input is a regular file, this works nicely and pFormatCtx is populated with the streams in the file. However, when i set input to "pipe:", av_find_stream_info returns with -1.

I am using the same file and piping it by running
`cat mpeg.ts | myApp`

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Aliza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the file I was using was too short.

`av_format_open_input` reads 8K of the file & `av_find_stream_info` reads according to max_analyze_duration (of the `AVFormatContext`).

Since my file was too short, it reached the end of the pipe before it reached `max_analyze_duration` and therefore returned -1.

I still am not sure why it worked with a regular file - maybe it seeked back to the beginning after the call to `av_format_open_input`.

In any case, I was able to solve he problem by setting `max_analyze_duration` to a smaller value, or by using a longer file.

Answer (score 0):

This is from this [article](http://iosvideokit.com/2014/02/13/minimizing-the-initial-delay/) about reducing latency and [ffmpeg streaming guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Latency)

You can give minimum values for probesize and maximum analyze duration.

```
pFormatCtx->probesize = 32;
pFormatCtx->max_analyze_duration = 32;
```

> Also, please note that the smaller values are OK only for known
>   muxers, otherwise the connection may not be done because of lacking
>   data about stream.

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth noting that in case you are reading a **MOV** file from `stdin`, changing values of `probesize`/`analyzeduration` probably won't help. According to [this email thread](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-November/011084.html), it is a limitation of mov container format:

> It is not generally possible to read mov files via stdin,  because it
>   is perfectly normal that mov files contain  necessary information
>   needed for decoding (like codecs  etc.) at the very end of the file.
>   (This is not a limitation of FFmpeg, but a feature of the  mov file
>   format.)